# How to create an SQL Trigger which copies the selection from another Table,too?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Hello i created a SQL Trigger which copies the edited row and set a new ID. There is another table which is connected by the ids. its hard for me to explain i give you an example:

Table 1 with the Products:

```
ID           BEZEICHNUNG            PREIS

45           Coffee                 5,60
46           Tea                    2,20
```

Table 2 with the connection from Room to the Products:

```
ProductID          RoomID
45                 11
45                 46
46                 48
46                 41
```

When i update the price of the first row from Table 1, the Trigger creates a new row with a new ID like this:

```
ID           BEZEICHNUNG            PREIS

45           Coffee                 5,60
46           Tea                    2,20
47           Coffee                 4
```

My goal is to insert to the table 2 the new id with all the room ids which belongs to the old row.

It should look like this:

```
ProductID          RoomID
45                 11
45                 46
46                 48
46                 41
47                 11
47                 46
```

My current trigger look like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_UPDATE]
   ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
      SET  NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [DIENSTLEISTUNG] (BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
        PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
        AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
        AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
        UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, RUESTZEIT,
        PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
        ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,FLAG)

    SELECT  BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
        PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
        AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
        AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
        UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),RUESTZEIT,
        PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
        ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,
        0 
    FROM INSERTED

    UPDATE  DIENSTLEISTUNG
    SET     FLAG = 1 
    FROM    DIENSTLEISTUNG 
            INNER JOIN INSERTED
                ON INSERTED.ID = DIENSTLEISTUNG.ID
SET  NOCOUNT OFF;      
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the trigger, after the insert add

```
 SELECT @intNewID = Scope_Identity()
```

This gets the ID of the newly inserted product

```
 INSERT table2 (ProductID, RoomID)  
 SELECT @intNewID, RoomID
 FROM deleted
      INNER JOIN table2 on deleted.productid=table2.productid
```

This gets the products linked to the old product from the deleted, and copies them

Comment: In that case, add an OUTPUT clause to the INSERT statement, and join on that table.

Comment: it works thank you very much. could you explain your code a little bit?